Shaking the Arava on Hoshana Rabbah
I see in S.O. O Ch 564 (4) in the Rema that it is a custom not only to beat the Arava but also to shake it.

וי"א שצריך לנענע בה [טור בשם רש"י] ונהגו לעשות שתיהן מנענעין בה ואח"כ
חובטין אותה:
Rem"a: There are those who say that it must be shaken (Tur quoting
Rash"i). It is customary to do both; we shake it and then beat it.

I wonder why I see so few people in the Ashkenazi shuls I attend who shake the Arava.
related: Why do we beat the arava?

A few lines later he says the custom was to shake the arava when shaking the Lulav initially, but he doesn't like it. apparently when it got cut out of the earlier shaking ceremony, it never found a new home.
